# Issue when trying to emebed soundcloud via angularjs

Tags: angularjs, soundcloud

I'm using Soundclouds api to get the uri/permalink_url and then using their embed layout yet I keep getting this error.

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url={{sound.uri}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=https%3A%2F%2Fw.soundcloud.com%2Fplayer%2F%3Furl%3D%7B%7Bsound.uri%7D%7D
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:68:12)
    at Function.$interpolateMinErr.throwNoconcat (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:10727:9)
    at $interpolate (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:10979:30)
    at addAttrInterpolateDirective (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:8587:27)
    at collectDirectives (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:7724:13)
    at compileNodes (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:7551:22)
    at compileNodes (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:7567:15)
    at compileNodes (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:7567:15)
    at compileNodes (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:7567:15)
    at compileNodes (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js:7567:15) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

and in the template I added

```
<iframe ng-src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url={{sound.uri}}"></iframe>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$sce` service.
Sample Implementation

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $sce) {
    // ...
      var sampleUrl = "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=any_value"
      $scope.displayUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(sampleUrl);
}
```

On HTML side

```
<iframe ng-src="{{displayUrl}}"> </iframe>
```

Comment: A bit confused, so "any_variable" dynamically changes with displayUrl?

Comment: You can append that through your javascript code. 
Something like 
`var uri = $scope.sound.uri;
var sampleUrl = "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+uri;
$scope.displayUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(sampleUrl);`